# Template part not appended after menu element

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I am using the wordpress [walker class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) to append a template part after a menu `li`, however it is injecting the template parts above the entire menu structure. Here is what I've got

```
class bt_menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    public function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $dir = get_template_directory() . '/partials';
        // Get file names from 'partials' directory
        $scan = scandir($dir);
        // Get css class names from menu elements
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        foreach($scan as $file) {
            // Only grab files
            if (!is_dir("$file")) {
                // Just raw filenames
                $strip_extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                // Match css class with filenames
                if ($classes[0] == $strip_extension) {
                    // Append template part after closing </li>
                    $output .= "</li>" . get_template_part( 'partials/' . $strip_extension );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I've tested it, when I append other html to `$output` it displays directly after the closing `</li>` element as expected. Why does the `get_template_part` render above the menu structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the template parts output echo's directly to the browser and the menu is in $output and will be later outputed. (that`s probably realy bad english)

Turn on output buffering to get the output of the template part:

```
if ($classes[0] == $strip_extension) {
    // Append template part after closing </li>
    $output .= "</li>";
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'partials/' . $strip_extension );
    $output .= ob_get_clean();
}
```

See [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) for explanation.

---

By the way. A `<ul>` element should only contain `<li>` elements. Maybe this is not the best place for your extra output.